# PHP5.4 add extension error

Tags: php, xampp, windows-xp, dbase

I am having a problem adding an extention to PHP 5.4

I am running XAMPP 3.2.1 on Windows XP with PHP 5.4. Everything runs as expected.

But when I copy the php_dbase.dll to xampp/php/ext and and extension=php_dbase.dll to the php.ini file XAMMP will say:

- This application has failed to start because MSVCR110.dll was not found.
- PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library: 'C.\xampp\php\ext\php_dbase.dll' - The specific module could not be found

I did the same process on Windows 7 and it worked. But I need to do this on Windows XP.

Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012. Download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

> MSVCR110.dll is the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable dll that is needed for projects built with  Visual Studio 2011. The dll letters spell this out.
>   MS = Microsoft, V = Visual, C = C++, R = Redistributable
>   For Winroy to get started, this file is probably needed.
>   This error appears when you wish to run a software which require the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2012. The redistributable can easily be downloaded on the Microsoft website as x86 or x64 edition. Depending on the software you wish to install you need to install either the 32 bit or the 64 bit version. Refer the following link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

-- Yaqub K, Microsoft Support Engineer, 2013-08-20 from [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr110dll-is/f052d325-3af9-4ae5-990b-b080799724db)

Comment: Thank for the answer. The first error is gone but now:
PHP Startup: dbase: Unable to inirtialize module Module compiled wiht module API = 20121212 PHP compilied with module API = 20100525 These copies need to match.

Comment: Your version of PHP is too old to handle the module. Essentially you can update the version of PHP you are using, or find this module for the PHP version you are working with. I'll research

Comment: You can take a look at [this page](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/dbase/5.1.0/) for available downloads. It looks like they have only compiled version 5.1.0 - I believe that [this Thread Safe version](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/dbase/5.1.0/php_dbase-5.1.0-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip) is appropriate for XMAPP.